# Error in data.frame() arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 11, 10, 3, 5, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12, 22, 13, 16, 14, 15, 19, 17, 20, 18, 28, 2

Tags: r

I am using this command in R Studio to split the data present in one column:

`CTE.info <- data.frame(strsplit(as.character(CTE$V11),'|',fixed=TRUE))`

But, I am getting the error:

> Error in data.frame("orderItems", "79542;2;24.000;24.000;5.310", "Credit;1;-15.000;-15.000;.000",  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 11, 10, 3, 5, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12, 22, 13, 16, 14, 15, 19, 17, 20, 18, 28, 24

Could someone assist and let me know how can this be sorted?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the length of the list element same and it should work.

```
 lst <- strsplit(as.character(CTE$V11),'|',fixed=TRUE)
 d1 <- data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
 colnames(d1) <- paste0('V', seq_along(d1))
```

#### data

```
 CTE <- data.frame(V11= c('a|b|c', 'a|b', 'a|b|c|d'))
```

Comment: Thank you...It worked. I however not able to connect the records with their respective order ids properly. I am doing CTE.info3 <- cbind(CTE,d1) to connect back the data but the d1 data is not matching to the actual order id.